# create an app in flask-peewee

Tags: error-handling, peewee

am trying to create an app for user registration , whenever i try to insert the values in the database tan it will display an error :- TypeError: object() takes no parameters.

views.py

```
@app.route('/join/' , methods=['GET','POST'])
def join(): 

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['username']:

        try:
            user = User.select().where(User.username==request.form['username']).get()
            flash('That username is already taken')
        except: 
            #user = User.select().where(User.username==request.form['username']).get()

            user = User(username = request.form['username']) #, email = request.form['email'] , password = request.form['password'] )
#           user.set_password(request.form['password'] )
            user.save()
            auth.login_user(user)
            return 'dua me yaad rakhna'
#           return render_template('home')
#   else:
#       return 'HAAN G DEKHYa fer'

    return render_template("join.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still newbie to peewee, but I think the problem could be that you call the .login_user method with an wrong object.

```
auth.login_user(user)
```

Looking into actual flask-peewee documention (http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#creating-a-flask-app),

I recommend you a following process:

1. check versions of your Flask, Peewee and flask-peewee. Perhaps you use incompatible versions with API conflicts.
2. in case you use recent flask-peewee module, check if you have properly initialised
   **Peewee    Auth()** and **Admin()** classes. Author suggest more object oriented approach to user management than you have tried in your code.

If you are successful, please, share your findings ... :-)